# How to reorder columns in DataGrip or IntelliJ?

Tags: database, intellij-idea, alter-table, datagrip

How to reorder columns in table with DataGrip and/or IntelliJ?

Appropriate controls are inactive

[image]

Comment: Seems that you wont able to reorder columns with Datagrip, unless that you use MySQL. Please, see this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127352/how-do-i-enable-modify-column-order-in-datagrip

Answer (score 3):

It works only for MySQL due to the database syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [DB Browser for SQLite.](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

[image: 2]]